# Alerta success formulario

Tags: javascript, jquery, formularios, validación

Lo que sucede es lo siguiente tengo un formulario para registro y lo que quiero es que a lo que se registre salga un `sweetAlert`. El problema esta que al oprimir el boton sale el alert asi el formulario no este validado. Quisiera saber como hago para que el alert solo se muestre si el formulario esta completamente validado. Uso `formValidation.io` para validar mi formulario. Dejo el codigo de la validación:

```
$().ready(function () {

    $('#formularioRegistro').formValidation({// Validación datos capa cliente. TENER PRESENTE EL ID DEL FORM
        err: {container: 'tooltip'}, //muestra en tooltips
        icon: {valid: 'fa fa-thumbs-up', invalid: 'fa fa-thumbs-down', validating: 'fa fa-refresh'}, //iconos
        //locale: 'es_ES', //idioma - debe enlazar el archivo "es_ES.js"
        fields: {
            nombre: {//Validar con los aributos NAME de cada INPUT
                row: '.form-group',
                validators: {
                    notEmpty: {
                        message: 'Ingrese un nombre válido '

                    },
                    regexp: {
                        regexp: /^[a-zA-ZñÑáéíóúÁÉÍÓÚ/\s/a-zA-ZñÑáéíóúÁÉÍÓÚ]+$/,
                        message: 'Solo letras, sin números o carácteres especiales'
                    },
                    stringLength: {
                        min: 3,
                        message: 'Mínimo 3 carácteres'
                    }
                }
            },
            apellido: {//Validar con los aributos NAME de cada INPUT
                row: '.form-group',
                validators: {
                    notEmpty: {
                        message: 'Ingrese un apellido válido'
                    },
                    regexp: {
                        regexp: /^[a-zA-ZñÑáéíóúÁÉÍÓÚ/\s/a-zA-ZñÑáéíóúÁÉÍÓÚ]+$/,
                        message: 'Solo letras, sin números o carácteres especiales'
                    },
                    stringLength: {
                        min: 3,
                        message: 'Mínimo 3 carácteres'
                    }
                }
            },
            documento: {//Validar con los aributos NAME de cada INPUT
                row: '.form-group',
                validators: {
                    notEmpty: {
                        message: 'Ingrese un documento válido'
                    },
                    regexp: {
                        regexp: /^[0-9]+$/,
                        message: 'Solo números'
                    },
                    stringLength: {
                        min: 5,
                        message: 'Mínimo 5 carácteres'
                    }
                }
            },
            correo: {//Validar con los aributos NAME de cada INPUT
                row: '.form-group',
                validators: {
                    notEmpty: {
                        message: 'Ingrese un correo válido'
                    },
                    regexp: {
                        regexp: /^[_a-z0-9-]+(\.[_a-z0-9-]+)*@[a-z0-9-]+(\.[a-z0-9-]+)*(\.[a-z]{2,3})$/,
                        message: 'No se aceptan carácteres especiales'
                    },
                    stringLength: {
                        min: 5,
                        message: 'Mínimo 5 carácteres'
                    }
                }
            },
            contrasena: {//Validar con los aributos NAME de cada INPUT
                row: '.form-group',
                validators: {
                    notEmpty: {
                        message: 'Ingrese una contraseña válida'
                    },
                    regexp: {
                        regexp: /^[a-zA-ZñÑáéíóúÁÉÍÓÚ0-9]+$/,
                        message: 'No se aceptan carácteres especiales'
                    },
                    stringLength: {
                        min: 5,
                        message: 'Minimo 5 carácteres'
                    }
                }
            },
            repetirContraseña: {//Validar con los aributos NAME de cada INPUT
                row: '.form-group',
                validators: {
                    notEmpty: {
                        message: 'Las contraseñas no coinciden'
                    },
                    regexp: {
                        regexp: /^[a-zA-ZñÑáéíóúÁÉÍÓÚ0-9]+$/,
                        message: 'No se aceptan carácteres especiales'
                    },
                    stringLength: {
                        min: 5,
                        message: 'Minimo 5 carácteres'
                    },
                    identical: {
                        field: 'contraseña',
                        message: 'Las contraseñas no coinciden'
                    }
                }
            },
            direccion: {//Validar con los aributos NAME de cada INPUT
                row: '.form-group',
                validators: {
                    notEmpty: {
                        message: 'Ingrese una dirección válida'
                    },
                    regexp: {
                        regexp: /^[a-zA-ZñÑáéíóúÁÉÍÓÚ0-9/\s/a-zA-ZñÑáéíóúÁÉÍÓÚ]+$/,
                        message: 'No se aceptan carácteres especiales'
                    },
                    stringLength: {
                        min: 10,
                        message: 'Mínimo 10 carácteres'
                    }
                }
            },
            tel: {//Validar con los aributos NAME de cada INPUT
                row: '.form-group',
                validators: {
                    notEmpty: {
                        message: 'Ingrese un télefono válido'
                    },
                    regexp: {
                        regexp: /^[0-9-]+$/,
                        message: 'Sólo numeros'
                    },
                    stringLength: {
                        min: 7,
                        message: 'Mínimo 7 carácteres'
                    }
                }

            },
            ciudad: {
                validators: {
                    callback: {
                        message: 'Debe elegir su ciudad',
                        callback: function (value, validator, $field) {
                            // Get the selected options
                            var options = validator.getFieldElements('ciudad').val();
                            return (options !== null && options.length >= 1 && options.length <= 4);
                        }
                    }
                }
            },
               genero: {
                validators: {
                    callback: {
                        message: 'Debe elegir su género',
                        callback: function (value, validator, $field) {
                            // Get the selected options
                            var options = validator.getFieldElements('genero').val();
                            return (options !== null && options.length >= 1 && options.length <= 10);
                        }
                    }
                }
            },
            'confirmar[]': {
                row: '.form-group',
                validators: {
                    notEmpty: {
                        message: 'Debe aceptar términos y condiciones'
                    },
                    stringLength: {
                        max: 1,
                        message: 'Debe aceptar términos y condiciones'
                    }
                }
            }


        }
    });
});
```

> Se que existe un evento llamado success.form.fv pero no se como implementarlo la alerta de sweetAlert que quiero que salga es:
>
> swal("Registrado correctamente!", "Gracias por registrarte!", "success")

Gracias por ayudarme.

---

Mira mi formulario es este:

Registro de usuarios

```
                                <!-- nombre-->
                                <div class="form-group">
                                    <label class="col-md-4 control-label" for="nombre" >Nombres:</label>  
                                    <div class="col-md-6">
                                        <input id="nombre" name="nombre" type="text" placeholder="" maxlength="30" class="form-control input-md"   tabindex="1" ></input>
                                    </div>
                                </div>

                                <!-- Apellido-->
                                <div class="form-group">
                                    <label class="col-md-4 control-label" for="apellido">Apellidos:</label>  
                                    <div class="col-md-6">
                                        <input id="apellido" name="apellido" type="text" maxlength="30" placeholder="" class="form-control input-md"  tabindex="2"></input>
                                    </div>
                                </div>

                                <!-- Documento-->
                                <div class="form-group">
                                    <label class="col-md-4 control-label" for="documento">N° Documento:</label>  
                                    <div class="col-md-6">
                                        <input id="documento" name="documento" type="text" maxlength="10" placeholder="" class="form-control input-md"  tabindex="3"></input>
                                    </div>
                                </div>
                                <!-- Email-->

                                <div class="form-group">
                                    <label class="col-md-4 control-label" for="correo">E-mail:</label>  
                                    <div class="col-md-6">
                                        <input id="correo"  name="correo" type="email" class="form-control"  placeholder="abcde@hotmail.com"  tabindex="4"   ></input>
                                    </div>
                                </div>
                                <!-- Contraseña-->
                                <div class="form-group">
                                    <label class="col-md-4 control-label" for="contrasena">Contraseña:</label>  
                                    <div class="col-md-6">
                                        <input id="contrasena"  name="contrasena" type="password" class="form-control" placeholder="********"  tabindex="5" ></input> 
                                    </div>
                                </div>
                                <!-- Confirmar contraseña-->
                                <div class="form-group">
                                    <label class="col-md-4 control-label" for="repetirContraseña">Confirmar contraseña:</label>  
                                    <div class="col-md-6">
                                        <input id="repetirContraseña" name="repetirContraseña" type="password" class="form-control" placeholder="********"  tabindex="6"></input>
                                    </div>
                                </div>
                                <!-- Direccion-->
                                <div class="form-group">
                                    <label class="col-md-4 control-label" for="direccion">Dirección:</label>  
                                    <div class="col-md-6">
                                        <input id="direccion" name="direccion" type="text" placeholder="" class="form-control input-md" maxlength="50" tabindex="7"></input>

                                    </div>
                                </div>

                                <!-- Telefono-->
                                <div class="form-group">
                                    <label class="col-md-4 control-label" for="tel">Teléfono:</label>  
                                    <div class="col-md-6">
                                        <input id="tel" name="tel" type="text" maxlength="15" placeholder="" class="form-control input-md"  tabindex="8"></input>
                                    </div>
                                </div>

                                <!-- Ciudad -->
                                <div class="form-group">
                                    <label class="col-md-4 control-label" for="ciudad">Ciudad de residencia:</label>
                                    <div class="col-md-6">
                                        <select id="ciudad" name="ciudad" class="form-control"  tabindex="10" >
                                            <option selected="true" disabled="true">Seleccione Ciudad...</option>
                                            <c:forEach var="objCiudad" items="#{controladorCiudad.listarCiudades()}">
                                                <option value="#{objCiudad.idCiudad}">#{objCiudad.nombreCiudad}</option>
                                            </c:forEach>
                                        </select>
                                    </div>
                                </div>
                                <!-- Fecha -->
                                <div class="form-group">
                                    <label class="col-md-4 control-label" for="fechaN">Fecha de Nacimiento:</label>  
                                    <div class="col-md-6">
                                        <input id="fechaN" name="fechaN" type="date" placeholder="" class="form-control input-md" max="1998-04-07" min="1950-12-31" tabindex="11"></input>
                                    </div>
                                </div>

                                <div class="form-group">
                                    <label class="col-md-4 control-label" for="genero">Género:</label>
                                    <div class="col-md-6">
                                        <select id="genero" name="genero" class="form-control"  tabindex="10" >
                                            <option selected="true" disabled="true">Seleccione Genero...</option>
                                            <option value="Masculino">Masculino</option>
                                            <option value="Femenino">Femenino</option>

                                        </select>
                                    </div>
                                </div>



                                <div class="form-group">
                                    <div class="col-sm-offset-1 col-sm-10">
                                        <div class="checkbox">
                                            <label class="col-md-5 control-label"></label>
                                            <div class="col-md-8">
                                                <label><input type="checkbox" id="confirmar" name="confirmar" ></input>Acepto términos y condiciones</label>
                                            </div>
                                        </div>
                                    </div>
                                </div>

                                <div id="condicion" class="col-md-12">
                                    <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-info-sign" aria-hidden="true"></span>
                                    <u>Para registarse en Effective Orders debe diligenciar todos los campos</u>
                                </div> 

                                <!-- Boton -->
                                <div id="boton">
                                    <div class="form-group">
                                        <label class="col-md-4 control-label" for="Boton"></label>
                                        <div class="col-md-4">
                                            <h:commandButton id="Boton" type="submit" class="btn btn-success" value="Registrarme" action="#{controladorUsuario.registrarUsuario()}" tabindex="12"></h:commandButton>
                                        </div>
                                    </div>
                                </div>
                            </h:form>
```

> Y la validación es el script que puse de primeras

---

Leandro hola, me sirve de maravilla hasta que ingreso selects, ahí si solo lleno este campo de una vez manda la alerta me podrias ayudar? gracias

```js
var isvalid = false;

$(function() {
  
    $('#profileForm').formValidation({
        framework: 'bootstrap',
        icon: {
            valid: 'glyphicon glyphicon-ok',
            invalid: 'glyphicon glyphicon-remove',
            validating: 'glyphicon glyphicon-refresh'
        },
        fields: {
            firstName: {
                row: '.col-xs-4',
                validators: {
                    notEmpty: {
                        message: 'The first name is required'
                    }
                }
            },
            lastName: {
                row: '.col-xs-4',
                validators: {
                    notEmpty: {
                        message: 'The last name is required'
                    }
                }
            }
        }
    }).on('err.field.fv', function(e, data) {
         isvalid = false;
    }).on('success.field.fv', function(e, data) {
         isvalid = true;
    });;

    $('#setValueButton').on('click', function() {
      
      $('form').data('formValidation').validate();
      
      if(isvalid){
        alert("es valido");
      }
      
    });
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.9.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/formvalidation/0.6.1/js/formValidation.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/formvalidation/0.6.1/js/framework/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
<link href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.6/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
<script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.6/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>




<form id="profileForm" class="form-horizontal">
    <div class="form-group">
        <label class="col-xs-3 control-label">Full name</label>
        <div class="col-xs-4">
            <input type="text" class="form-control" name="firstName" placeholder="First name" />
        </div>
        <div class="col-xs-4">
            <input type="text" class="form-control" name="lastName" placeholder="Last name" />
        </div>
    </div>

    <div class="form-group">
        <div class="col-xs-9 col-xs-offset-3">
            <button type="button" class="btn btn-primary" id="setValueButton">Set values</button>
        </div>
    </div>
</form>
```

Comment: en el codigo que muestras veo las validaciones, pero donde realizas la muestra del alert ?

Comment: El alert lo tengo en el boton como un evento de javascript. Lo que necesito es lo que escribes, mostrar el alert según la validación.

Comment: Alerta, Alerta, esto es stack en español.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Analiza esta implementacion.

Veras como se hace uso del `err.field.fv` y `success.field.fv` para asignar un flag que permite trabjar con el boton mostrando el alert.

En tu caso reemplaza el alert de javascript por el de sweetAlert.

```js
var isvalid = false;

$(function() {
  
    $('#profileForm').formValidation({
        framework: 'bootstrap',
        icon: {
            valid: 'glyphicon glyphicon-ok',
            invalid: 'glyphicon glyphicon-remove',
            validating: 'glyphicon glyphicon-refresh'
        },
        fields: {
            firstName: {
                row: '.col-xs-4',
                validators: {
                    notEmpty: {
                        message: 'The first name is required'
                    }
                }
            },
            lastName: {
                row: '.col-xs-4',
                validators: {
                    notEmpty: {
                        message: 'The last name is required'
                    }
                }
            }
        }
    }).on('err.field.fv', function(e, data) {
         isvalid = false;
    }).on('success.field.fv', function(e, data) {
         isvalid = true;
    });;

    $('#setValueButton').on('click', function() {
      
      $('form').data('formValidation').validate();
      
      if(isvalid){
        alert("es valido");
      }
      
    });
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.9.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/formvalidation/0.6.1/js/formValidation.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/formvalidation/0.6.1/js/framework/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
<link href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.6/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
<script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.6/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>




<form id="profileForm" class="form-horizontal">
    <div class="form-group">
        <label class="col-xs-3 control-label">Full name</label>
        <div class="col-xs-4">
            <input type="text" class="form-control" name="firstName" placeholder="First name" />
        </div>
        <div class="col-xs-4">
            <input type="text" class="form-control" name="lastName" placeholder="Last name" />
        </div>
    </div>

    <div class="form-group">
        <div class="col-xs-9 col-xs-offset-3">
            <button type="button" class="btn btn-primary" id="setValueButton">Set values</button>
        </div>
    </div>
</form>
```

Comment: Leandro hola, me sirve de maravilla hasta que ingreso selects, ahí si solo lleno este campo de una vez manda la alerta me podrias ayudar? gracias

Comment: no entendi, como es eso de los select ? la validacion asigna a la variable isvalid si esta pasa o no, pero luego esta la usas donde necesites si es en el click de un boton no veo porque el select la deba afectar